# ASP.NET Core 6.0 => Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm getting an error in custom exception handling after using ASP.NET Core 6.0:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor..ctor(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.OutputFormatterSelector, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.IHttpResponseStreamWriterFactory, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory)'.
>
> at JMCKnow.Domain.Results.RequestFailedResultExecutor..ctor(OutputFormatterSelector formatterSelector, IHttpResponseStreamWriterFactory writerFactory, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions) at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType) at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
> at JMCKnow.Domain.Helpers.HttpContextExtensions.WriteResultAsync[TResult](HttpContext context, TResult result) in D:\localhost\JMC\jmc-know-api\JMCKnow\JMCKnow.Domain\Helpers\HttpContextExtensions.cs:line 24
> at JMCKnow.Api.Middlewares.CustomExceptionMiddleware.HandleNotFoundExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, NotFoundException exception) in D:\localhost\JMC\jmc-know-api\JMCKnow\JMCKnow.Api\Middlewares\CustomExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 124
> at JMCKnow.Api.Middlewares.CustomExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext) in D:\localhost\JMC\jmc-know-api\JMCKnow\JMCKnow.Api\Middlewares\CustomExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 60
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esh6x.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYmgn.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Usually it is sign of some library version mismatch. Can you please share your .csproj file? And please share the code as text, not images.

Comment: Did you do half a deploy? Like there's still some .NET 5 assemblies lying around in your publish directory?

Comment: First image indicates you are getting an HTTP error 404.  The connection is completing and the server detected an error. 404 indicates the page is not found.

Comment: Could you spcific your purpose?The first pciture indicates you are handling validation errors(400) why you return NotFound Result（404）？And what's RequestFailedResult(why not BadRequestResult)? Could you show more details?

Comment: This is resolve and issue regarding referance in class library of .net core 6.0